# Load a Javascript in another Javascript in Play-scala Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, playframework

How can we load another javascript in js file in Playframe work
This is my conf file

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
POST    /upload                     controllers.Application.uploadFile

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

I tried a to load js file:

```
(function(window){

  var RECORDER_WORKER_PATH  = '/javascripts/recordWorker.js")';
  var ENCODER_WORKER_PATH   = '/javascripts/mp3Worker.js")';
```

but i ended up with this in the webconsole:

```
Error:ScriptFile not found at 'javascripts/recordWorker.js
Error:ScriptFile not found at 'javascripts/mp3Worker.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static assets are served under `/assets/*` per your definition in the `routes` file.
You should therefore prepend `/assets/` to your URIs.

```
(function(window){

    var RECORDER_WORKER_PATH  = '/assets/javascripts/recordWorker.js")';
    var ENCODER_WORKER_PATH   = '/assets/javascripts/mp3Worker.js")';
```

See [Play Asset controller docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets#The-Assets-controller) for more details.